# adding a background image in css

Tags: css

I am new to web development and I want to display an image for my background.Only problem is that my image will not show, may you please help me. Below is my code

```
<style type="text/css">
.bgimg {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url("worldtravlerissue1.jpg");
    min-height: 90%;


 }
</style>
```

Comment: What type of element is `.bgimg`?

Comment: Can you add code snippet?

Comment: The information you provided is not sufficient for help. However, I'm going to suggest two things for you.
1. Make sure you are calling that class called bgimg in your code properly. no typo etc
2. Make sure the url file path is correct.

Comment: use absolute path.. example http://............ also take this path and launch it in a browser to determine if the browser can locate the image

Comment: @repzero That's assuming the path is the issue. I think it's more likely the element has no width. But until we see the HTML, no one knows.

Comment: @DrewKennedy with the question above, we can't rule out any little thing

Answer (score 1):

1)Be sure the div has a concrete width and height, if you're using % be sure the image div is inside another with a height and width declaration on css
2)Be sure you've declared the right class
3)Be sure the img url is right and you're reaching the right path

```css
.img{
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  background-image: url(https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/RGRIEDX4IU.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You're image might not be showing because either you have the wrong name for it, wrong extension as in assuming its a `.jpg` rather than `.png` or .`jpeg` **or** its not in the same directory as your HTML file. Make sure they are in the same folder or directory a.k.a Desktop.

If you have your HTML file on your desktop and the picture is in a different folder, you'd have to do

```
background-image: url("NAMEOFFOLDER/worldtravlerissue1.jpg");
```

Hope that helped.